# Fixing color rendering in openGL with glScalef

Tags: opengl, mirroring

I'm using `glScalef (-1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` to flip my openGL image axis. However this completely messes up the rendering of the objects and the colors. I've tried the following things to no avail:

```
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST) ;
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
```

If I flip in x and y - `glScalef (-1.0, -1.0, 1.0)` then the colors are fine, but I don't want to flip both dimensions. Flipping x and z does not fix the colors.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You changed the handedness of your coordinate space by doing this. Effectively when it comes time to rasterize your triangles, the front becomes the back because the winding direction is reversed.

You should be aware of how the rasterizer determines the front/back face of a polygon. It uses the post-projected position of your vertices and tests the winding direction. You flipped 1-axis in your post-projected coordinate system, which changes handedness (more formally, its [chirality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality)). This produces a mirror image and the winding of your vertices is backwards.

You can solve this with `glFrontFace (GL_CW)`, or simply wind your vertices the other way by hand.